# Arrow splitting scene in Robin Hood: Prince of Thieves

Tags: robin-hood-prince-of-thieves

I remember in the Kevin Costner Robin Hood movie that there was a scene where Robin splits an arrow in half with an arrow shot.  I tried going through the movie but couldn’t find such a scene.  Did I imagine it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you did not imagine it.

Here's the scene, and the arrow split shot happens at 3:08